# When do we have $\sigma(X)= \sigma (f(X))$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

If $X$ is a real random variable and $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow A \subseteq \mathbb R$ a measurable function.

In general, we have $\sigma (f(X)) \subseteq \sigma (X)$. Is there a function different from the identity that yields $\sigma (f(X)) = \sigma (X)$ ? If it is possible, what class of functions yields $\sigma (f(X)) = \sigma (X)$ ?

Comment: Maybe invertible functions $f$?

Comment: @angryavian I was thinking suspecting bijective functions, but maybe injective is enough ? What we need is that for any Borel set $B_1$, we have $B_1=f^{-1}(B_2)$ where $B_2$ is a Borel set, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any injective measurable function will do. It is a well-known fact from descriptive set theory that an injective Borel measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ sends Borel sets to Borel sets. So for every Borel set $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have that $f(B)$ is a Borel set and $(f\circ X)^{-1}(f(B))=X^{-1}\circ f^{-1}(f(B))=X^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was expecting. I was stuck at showing that $f(B)$ is Borel when $B$ is Borel and $f$ injective mesurable. Do you have a reference ?

Comment: This is, for example, Theorem 12.29 in "Infinite Dimensional Analysis" (2003) by Aliprantis and Border.