# A question about sigma-algebras: $\sigma(Y+f(X))= \sigma(Y+X)$ if $\sigma(f(X))= \sigma(X)$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two independent real random variables. Let $f$ be an injective mesurable real function, which means $\sigma(f(X))= \sigma (X)$, see [When do we have $\sigma(X)= \sigma (f(X))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329417/when-do-we-have-sigmax-sigma-fx)

Is it true that we also have $\sigma(Y+f(X))= \sigma(Y+X)$ ? Does the fact that we have independence of $X$ and $Y$ play a role ?

Comment: One the role of independence between $X$ and $Y$, consider $Y=-f(X)$.

Comment: But even if you have independence you can play tricks with 0-probability events.  Suppose $f(x)=2x$. Say $X$ and $Y$ are independent uniform over $[0,1]$, and they take values in $[0,1]$ for all but two outcomes.   However, there are two probability-0 outcomes $\omega_1, \omega_2$ under which $(X(\omega_1), Y(\omega_1))=(100, -100)$ and $(X(\omega_2), Y(\omega_2)) = (200, -200)$.  Then $Y(\omega_1)+X(\omega_1) = Y(\omega_2)+X(\omega_2)$ but $Y(\omega_1)+f(X(\omega_1)) \neq Y(\omega_2) + f(X(\omega_2))$. So $\{\omega_2\} = \{Y+f(X)=200\} \in \sigma(Y+f(X))$, $\{\omega_2\} \notin \sigma(Y+X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expands my comments: With or without independence, we can get examples where
$\sigma(Y+f(X)) \neq \sigma(Y+X)$.

Throughout, assume $f(x) = 2x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

- Example 1:  Let $\Omega=[0,1]$ be the sample space.  Suppose we use the Borel sigma algebra and Borel measure. Define random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
  $$ X(\omega) = \left\{\begin{array}{c}
  1 & \mbox{$\omega>0$} \\
  0 & \mbox{$\omega = 0$} 
  \end{array}.\right.$$
  Then $P[X=1]=1$ and so $X$ is independent of every random variable (including $-2X$). Define $Y=-2X$.  Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent and
  \begin{align}
  &\sigma(Y+2X)= \sigma(0) = \{\phi, \Omega\}\\
  &\sigma(Y+X) = \sigma(-X) = \sigma(X) = \{\phi, \Omega, \{X=0\}, \{X=1\}\}
  \end{align}
  So $\sigma(Y+2X) \neq \sigma(Y+X)$.
- Example 2: This example has $X$ and $Y$ i.i.d. and uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. Let $\Omega$ be a sample space. Let $U, V$ be independent random variables that are uniform over $[0,1]$ with $$\{U(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}: \omega \in \Omega\} = \{V(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}: \omega \in \Omega\} = [0,1]$$
  Define $(X,Y)$ by:
  $$ (X,Y) = \left\{\begin{array},
  (U,V) & \mbox{ if $U\in (0,1)$}\\
  (100, -100) & \mbox{ if $U=0$} \\
  (200, -200)  & \mbox{ if $U=1$}  
  \end{array}\right.$$
  Since $P[U \in (0,1)]=1$ we have that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. However,
  $$ \{U=1\} = \{Y+2X = 200\} \in \sigma(Y+2X) $$
  On the other hand
  $$ \{U=1\} \notin \sigma(Y+X)$$
  To see this, define $A = \{U=1\}\cup \{U=0\}$. Note that if $v<0$ then no elements of $A$ are in $\{Y+X\leq v\}$; if $v\geq 0$ then all elements of $A$ are in $\{Y+X\leq v\}$. But these sets $\{Y+X\leq v\}$ generate $\sigma(Y+X)$. So every set in $\sigma(Y+X)$ contains either all elements of $A$ or no elements of $A$.    So $\{U=1\}$ is not in $\sigma(Y+X)$ because $\{U=1\}$ contains at least one element of $A$ but not all elements of $A$.